# Odoo restrict analytic line with date

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to restrict the Analytic line with a date rule so that the employyes cant add hours more than X days from the current date. The reason we want to restrict this is so that they would put in their project hours faster (They get the salary based on this too).

Any suggestions on how to limit the days they have?

Im using a [('user_id','=',user.id)] rule for the regular users so that they cant add hours for their co-workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your domain would be something like the following in views

```xml
<field name="domain">
[('user_id','=',user.id) ,
  ('date', '<=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) )]
</field>
```

or in python file as

```py
[('user_id','=',user.id), ('date', '<=', ((datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) )]
```

Comment: I'm getting a error with the suggested rule. ValueError: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: "name 'context_today' is not defined" while evaluating u"[[('user_id','=',user.id)] ,\n ('date', '<=', ((context_today()+datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%d-%‌​m-%Y')) – Simon Gottberg 1 hour ago

Comment: is it in python file or xml file??

Comment: I added it to the existing rules (domain filter) – Simon Gottberg 4 hours ago

Comment: ok you can try this
(datetime.datetime.utcnow()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Thx, will try it later!

Comment: what was the problem